# Query value starting with dash causes elasticsearch count api to fail

Tags: elasticsearch

This works:

```
GET /box/item/_count?q=name%3Aabcdef
```

This doesn't:

```
GET /box/item/_count?q=name%3A-abcdef
```

(The difference is the dash)

Reply from elasticsearch is: "Cannot parse 'name:-abcdeft'"

box/item is not_analyzed.

What to do?

Comment: use quotes for name parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escaping it with a backslash works for me:

```
GET /box/item/_count?q=name%3A\-abcdef
```

so does using quotes:

```
GET /box/item/_count?q=name%3A"-abcdef"
```

The hyphen is a special character and like others needs to be escaped:

> reserved characters
>
> If you need to use any of the characters which function as operators
>   in your query itself (and not as operators), then you should escape
>   them with a leading backslash. For instance, to search for (1+1)=2,
>   you would need to write your query as \(1\+1\)=2.
>
> The reserved characters are: + - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /
>
> Failing to escape these special characters correctly could lead to a
>   syntax error which prevents your query from running.